# when we use createSlice we handle sideEffect using createAsyncThunk() function ,any way to achieve this functionality in saga style?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialValue = {
    value: 0,
    name: "praful"
}

export const nameChange = createAsyncThunk(
    'fetchname',
    async () => {
        let result = await axios.get(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=VesHGy2A&page=1&per_page=30`).then((data) => data.data)
        return result[0].user.name
    }
)

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "Counter",
    initialState: initialValue,
    reducers: {
        increment: (state) => {
            state.value += 1
        },
        decrement: (state) => {
            state.value -= 1
        },
        incrementByAmoount: (state, action) => {
            state.value += action.payload
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [nameChange.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.name = action.payload
        },
        [nameChange.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.name = "Loding "
        },
        [nameChange.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.name = "Error"
        }
    }
})
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmoount } = counterSlice.actions
export default counterSlice.reducer
```

like in react-redux we use saga and it work like watcher and based on that they set data ,so how achieve this functionality in redux-toolkit when we use createSlice .in above code we have use createAsyncThunk for handing sideEffect

Answer (score 1):

The point is pretty much *not to use saga*.

The Redux Style guide recommends [Thunks as the default](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic), since sagas may excel in very complicated async use cases, but almost no applications have those use cases. Data fetching is certainly not one of them.

If you know you need saga, still use saga. (It's still 100% possible in RTK.)

But for something as simple as a "execute this and dispatch a few actions before and after", you just don't need saga. I'd argue that even when using saga, you probably should use thunks for everything you don't *need* sagas for.

Comment: Ok sir, thanks for clear my doubt